# Add travel preferences to Careers

Tags: feature-request, jobs, preferences

There should be some way to indicate willingness (or unwillingness) to travel and the percentage of travel one is willing to accept.

Comment: i had to check, i thought for sure that was there already, but it isn't!

Comment: I'd swear I remembered seeing that before too.  Huh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep in mind that the site caters to companies searching for rockstar developers.

When the companies start asking for that feature, specifically in the context of searching for developers with specific travel preferences, then it will be implemented.

Comment: I think the searching issue is why it might be sub optimal to add it to a personal statement as Joel suggests (although that seems like a good compromise for the moment).

Answer (score 2):

In the interest in keeping things simple, isn't it enough just to add it to your personal statement?